# Is this usage of hyphen in regex valid?

Tags: javascript, regex, email

*NB. I **only** want to know if it's a valid application of unescaped hyphen in the regex definition. It's **not** a question about matching email, meaning of hyphen nor backslash, quantifiers or anything else. Also, please note that the linked in answer doesn't really discuss the validity issue between escaped/unescaped hyphen.*

Usually I declare the regex for matching email addresses like this.

```
var emailPattern = /^[a-z.\-_]+@[a-z]+[.]{1}[a-z]{2,3}$/;
emailPattern.test('ss.a_a-@ass.com');
```

Now, by mistake, a colleague of mine forgot the escape character and **still* made it work, which surprised me, because of the interval meaning of the hyphen. It looks like this.

```
var weirdPattern = /^[a-z._-]+@[a-z]+[.]{1}[a-z]{2,3}$/;
weirdPattern.test('ss.a_a-@ass.com');
```

Apparently, it works because the hyphen is the last character in the brackets. My question is if this is just a happy coincidence or if it's a valid syntax? Have I been regexing wrong my whole life?

Comment: *Have I been regexing wrong my whole life?* - you were overescaping, but it is not *wrong*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hyphens inside character class are used for range. However, when put at the beginning or at the end inside character class there is no need of escaping that.

<strike>Note that, in some browsers, hyphens at any position in the character class are still considered as range metacharacters, so it is best practice to always escape it.</strike>

Quoting from [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

> The **hyphen can be included right after the opening bracket, or right before the closing bracket, or right after the negating caret**. Both `[-x]` and `[x-]` match an `x` or a hyphen. `[^-x]` and `[^x-]` match any character that is not an `x` or a hyphen. **Hyphens at other positions in character classes where they can't form a range may be interpreted as literals or as errors.** Regex flavors are quite inconsistent about this.

Comment: Also, you could include what `[#--0]` would match.

Comment: I understand what you say and can confirm that it works indeed. I can also imagine that it sometimes breaks and should be escaped for safety's sake. The question is, however, if it's a valid syntax. Definitionwise and academicly speaking.

Comment: @KonradViltersten That depends on how the regex engine has implemented it. For widely used browsers it works.

Comment: I have never heard of a browser that requires to escape a hyphen at the beginning of the character class to be treated as a literal. Could you name one? Konrad, **it is a totally valid syntax** that has its stems in the POSIX standard where characters inside a character class cannot be escaped.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't remember correctly but I've seen the same on a post on SO and the browser name(_again not sure_) is Komodo

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've made even more explicit disclaimer. Feel free to review it. I fear you were a bit too trigger happy marking it as a dupe. I can't see the actual answer to **my** question there. Those are more of *how-to* not *why-and-why-not*, in my opinion.

Comment: @Tushar: This? [*Komodo can accept Python syntax regular expressions in it's various Search features.*](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/regex-intro.html) - there is a really weird thing about the Python regex that does not allow unescaped hyphen after shorthand character classes (do not use `[\w-,]` in Python). But you do not have to escape `-` at the start/end of a character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I remember that I've seen it in SO post, but not able to search now

Comment: From what I know, there is only one single engine requiring to escape the hyphen at the end of the character class -  Elasticsearch. All other flavors allow you to use unescaped literal hyphens both at the beginning/end.

Comment: @Tushar You forgot to mention that it will also match `everything` between `#` and `-`. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lI2oL5/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've made it community wiki, can you please edit it to add more details.

Comment: You did not have to, and you can ask moderators to revert it to a normal answer :) If I have time, I will add.